# Обособление относительного местоимения

Tags: пунктуация

*Мне просто было некогда. А ты думал почему?*

Обособляется ли "почему"?

Answer (score 1):

***Мне просто было некогда. А тЫ думал,  почемУ?***

Правила Розенталя позволяют обособлять или не обособлять одиночное союзное слово в зависимости от расстановки логических ударений (п. 4.3) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

Я полагаю, что здесь нужно выделить логическим ударением и местоимение ***ты***, и союзное слово ***почему***. Но в этом случае предложение нужно **разделить паузой на две части**.

При таком прочтении **запятая ставится**.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**А когда не ставим запятую?** ("Чтоб уж совсем понятно было").

*Мне просто было некогда. А ты, наверное, беспокоИлся, думал **почемУ***?

Здесь стандартная интонация (тоническое ударение в конце фразы), союзное слово ***почему*** входит в главное предложение.

Comment: То есть, если в устной речи предполагает обособление, то и в письменной? В данном случае это даже от интонации не зависит?

Comment: Розенталь в этой теме говорит о том, что следует учитывать интонацию.  Если же смотреть на постановку знаков препинания в целом, то они в большинстве случаев соответствуют как грамматике, так и интонации.  Например, здесь знаки можно поставить по интонации, но грамматическое объяснение также существует. При постановке запятой мы считаем союзное слово полноценным придаточным, а при отсутствии запятой включаем его в главное предложение.